¿Cómo unir los datos geoespaciales, para realizar un mapa con porcentajes en R?
datos <- read.csv("https://medata.gov.co/sites/default/files/distribution/1-026-22-000170/sivigila_violencia.csv")

datos_violencia <- datos %>%
  group_by(nombre_comuna) %>%
  summarise(casos = n()) %>%
  ungroup()

datos_violencia <- datos_violencia %>%
  mutate(porcentaje= (casos/ sum(casos))* 100)
print(datos_violencia)


mapa <- read_sf ("comunas_y_corregimientos.geojson")

names(mapa)
summary(mapa)

datos_violencia <- datos_violencia %>%
  mutate(porcentaje_char = as.character(porcentaje))

mapa <- mapa %>%
  mutate(NOMBRE_char = as.character(NOMBRE))

mapa_violencia <- mapa %>%
  left_join(datos_violencia, by = c("NOMBRE_char" = "nombre_comuna"))

print(names(mapa_violencia))
print(head(mapa_violencia))
print(sum(is.na(mapa_violencia$porcentaje)))

#tm_shape(mapa)

#tm_shape(mapa) + tm_polygons() + tm_layout(frame = FALSE)
mapa_plot <- tm_shape(mapa_violencia) +
  tm_fill("NOMBRE",  palette = "viridis", title = "Nombre") + # Ajusta el color y el título de la leyenda
tm_borders() +  # Agrega bordes para mejor visualización
  tm_text("NOMBRE", size = 0.5, col = "black", bg.col = "white", bg.alpha = 0.5) +

tm_layout(
    frame = FALSE,  # Elimina el marco del mapa
    legend.position = c(0.85, 0.1),  # Mueve la leyenda a la derecha y abajo
    legend.title.size = 1.2,  # Ajusta el tamaño del título de la leyenda
    legend.text.size = 0.8,
    inner.margins = c(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2)   # Ajusta el tamaño del texto de la leyenda

  )

# Mostrar el mapa
print(mapa_plot)

Necesito realizar  un mapa coroplético en donde se observe la distribución porcentual de
los casos de violencia de género en el Distrito de Medellín. sin embargo no se como unir los datos geoespaciales con los datos del porcentaje, el join no me funciona. intente convertir los dato dbl del porcentaje en char para ver si ese era el problema pero no, a la hora de imprimir el mapa y poner porcentaje no se imprime nada.
